File not getting delete through code flow in Progress4GL
If i run OS-DELETE using the same procedure editor it deletes but if i run through application it copies the file but the delete is not happening.
Code below:
WHEN "Processed" THEN 
DO:
    
    OS-COPY VALUE(TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath) VALUE(TT-ACT-FILES.ProcessedPath).

    /* Check if the copy operation resulted in an error */
    IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
        MESSAGE "Error copying file: " ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        RETURN.
    END.
    
    /* Debug message for the copy operation */
    MESSAGE "File copied successfully from :" (TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath) " to " (TT-ACT-FILES.ProcessedPath) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.

    /* Check if the source file exists before deletion */
    IF SEARCH(TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath) <> ? THEN DO:
        /* Attempt to delete the original file */
        OS-DELETE VALUE(TRIM(TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath)) NO-ERROR.

        /* Check if delete operation was successful */
        IF ERROR-STATUS:ERROR THEN DO:
            MESSAGE "Error deleting original file: " ERROR-STATUS:GET-MESSAGE(1) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
        END.
        ELSE
            MESSAGE "Original file deleted successfully." VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    END.
    ELSE
        MESSAGE "Source file does not exist for deletion: " (TRIM(TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath)) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
END.


Thankyou, I used that and I am getting OS-ERROR 2                                                          WHEN 2 THEN  MESSAGE "The file or directory you want to delete does not exist.". But when i checked the file exists on that path. Incase if I have more than one file it works fine till the last file. The last file is not getting deleted and at that time the OS-ERROR is 999.

You should check the OS-ERROR function after the OS-... statements.
https://docs.progress.com/de-DE/bundle/abl-reference/page/OS-ERROR-function.html

Thankyou, I used that and I am getting OS-ERROR 2                                                          WHEN 2 THEN  MESSAGE "The file or directory you want to delete does not exist.". But when i checked the file exists on that path. Incase if I have more than one file it works fine till the last file. The last file is not getting deleted and at that time the OS-ERROR is 999.

Errno 2 can also mean that you don't have permission.
/* first create "noperm.txt":
 *
 * sudo ls > /root/noperm.txt
 *
 */

file-info:filename = "/root/noperm.txt".

message file-info:full-pathname file-info:file-type.

os-delete value( file-info:full-pathname ).

message os-error.

I'm guessing that that is because a different user is running the program when it is being run "through the application".

The same code works in procedure editor. if i run through my application it doesn't. I am the only user working on it and there is no chance the file is in use by some other.

As Stefan mentions you do not need NO-ERROR after OS-DELETE.
In fact, that may very well be what your problem is.
file-info:filename = "xxx".

message file-info:full-pathname file-info:file-type.

os-delete value( file-info:full-pathname ) no-error.

message os-error.

Notice how the "xxx" file does get deleted but you still get errno 2? That is because NO-ERROR is being treated as an additional file name to be deleted. Don't believe me? Create a file called "no-error" when you create "xxx" and the errno 2 will disappear. So will the file called "no-error".

The search function searches the propath, OS-DELETE does not.
You also do not need the NO-ERRORs on OS-* statements.
Try:
when 'Processed' then do:

    session:appl-alert-boxes = true.
    
    os-copy value( TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath ) value( TT-ACT-FILES.ProcessedPath ).

    // Check if the copy operation resulted in an error
    if os-error > 0 then do:
        message 'Error copying file:' os-error.
        return.
    end.
    
    // Debug message for the copy operation 
    message 'File copied successfully from:' TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath 'to' TT-ACT-FILES.ProcessedPath.

    // Check if the source file exists before deletion
    if search( TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath ) <> ? then do:

        // Attempt to delete the original file
        os-delete value( search( TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath ) ).

        // Check if delete operation was successful 
        if os-error > 0 then
            message 'Error deleting original file:' os-error.
        else
            message 'Original file deleted successfully.'.

    end.
    else
        message 'Source file does not exist for deletion:' trim( TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath ).

end.


This indeed should be a valid solution but I have a feeling maybe TT-ACT-FILES.FilePath isnt really the complete file path. Maybe its relative and the original file has ended up in the wrong place to begins with...

It's not working even after using search, also the same code works in procedure editor. if i run through my application it doesn't. I am the only user working on it and there is no chance the file is in use by some other.
